# Show cookie-enabled Jquery notification message on page load

Tags: jquery, cookies, notifications, message

I've been through the forums and read many posts relating to my question, but I couldn't really find the answer I'm looking for.

I want to display a message with jquery to the user on page load and allow them to close the div by clicking on the close link. Once closed, the script should remember not to open again during that session. I guess it would use a cookie.

Here's the XHTML:

```
<div class="alertbox">
  <span class="message">Please upgrade your browser</span>
  <div class="bloc_navigateurs"> 
    <a href="http://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-3.6.13&amp;os=win&amp;lang=fr" target="_blank"><img src="includes/themes/default/images/icons/misc/Firefox-16.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Firefox" /></a>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/chrome?hl=fr" target="_blank"><img src="includes/themes/default/images/icons/misc/Chrome-16.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Chrome" /></a>
    <a href="http://www.01net.com/telecharger/windows/Internet/navigateur/fiches/13759.html" target="_blank"><img src="includes/themes/default/images/icons/misc/IE-16.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Internet Explorer " /></a>
  </div>
  <span class="close">close</span>
</div>
```

As you can see, this advises the IE6 user to upgrade their browser

Comment: ooops, very meaningful message :) I like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the [jQuery cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.cookie.js.txt).

Bind a handler for the close link's onclick event that creates the cookie.  Before displaying the div, check for the cookie.

```
<script>
$(function() {
  var $box = $(".alertbox"),
      stateCookieName = 'alertbox_state',
      alreadyClosed = $.cookie(stateCookieName);

  // The box should already be hidden initially (using CSS preferrably).
  // If not, uncomment the line below:
  // $box.hide();

  // Show the box if it hasn't already been closed.
  if (alreadyClosed != 1) {
    $box.show();
  }

  $box.find('.close').click(function() {
    $box.hide();
    $.cookie(stateCookieName, 1);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hey simshaun, thank you so much for such a fast reply. I just tested the suggested code and it didn't work. The div is still closed by CSS. I'm using Chrome 8

Comment: Can you post a URL so I can test?  It's late and my brain may be fried, but what I posted looks correct to me. :)

Comment: Hey Simshaun, it's a local project not hosted on the web yet. Do I still need to modify your code and also aadd the <script src="includes/js/scripts/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> file

Comment: @ simshaun, Sorry it is working except, I think the cookie part didn't quite work. The box is closing but it keeps loading on page load

Comment: Have Firebug? If so, get the Firecookie extension.  Once that's done, you'll be able to see if the cookie gets set correctly, as well its value.  (You can also view cookies through Page Info, but takes longer.)

Comment: @ simshaun, my bad. It is working in Firefox and IE9. I guess the issue is Chrome. But since I plan to use it to isolate IE6, I think we're fine here. Later on, I may be using this solution for a different purpose, but we'll let creativity deal with that part at that time. Thank you a million for your great help.

Answer (score 0):

get the cookie functions from [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) then you can set alertBox to be hidden by default and :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(readCookie('warnedIE')==null){
    $('.alertbox').show();
   createCookie('warnedIE','true',30);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you gonna find some help in that link:
http://www.thinkbohemian.com/2010/04/22/stack-overflow-style-notifications-using-jquery/